# How to build a shared library in android without using Android.mk file

Tags: android, makefile

I want to build a shared library in android without using `Android.mk` utilities i.e. `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`

Do not want to build the library officially with make build for android.

Comment: So, what did you plan on using instead? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hi Michael ,I have one module which I have to build as a library in android environment.one way is to write android.mk and build it.But with this if I do make build in android by default it will build all modules. My purpose is not to build the module as a shared library with make full build in android, instead I want to build it only when I define the particular target.

Comment: So you're building a full Android ROM, but sometimes you just want to build one specific module?  You can build the module in the current directory with `mm`, and the module at the given path with `mmm`

Comment: No, I dont also want to build it using mm or mmm. I want to write a simple Linux style makefile say module.mk and define a target in that module: and then build it using make module in android environment. Is it possible to do so.